# Could not open display (X-Server required. Check you DISPLAY variable)

Tags: debian, xorg, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mono-framework

I am trying to run a WinForm mono app from the command line without a full desktop environment. It opens correctly over SSH (using SmarTTY and X forwarding). However when I try to run it directly on the PI I get this.

The gist of it is "Could not open display (X-Server required. Check you DISPLAY variable)"

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException:
>   WinForms_SeeInnerException ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An
>   exception was thrown by the type initializer for
>   System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Could not open display (X-Server
>   required. Check you DISPLAY environment variable) Parameter name:
>   Display   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr
>   display_handle) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in :0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Theme.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---   at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in :0
>   at MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.MainForm..ctor () [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.My.MyProject+MyForms.Create__Instance__[MainForm]
>   (MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.MainForm Instance) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.My.MyProject+MyForms.get_MainForm () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run
>   (System.String[] commandLine) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.My.MyApplication.Main (System.String[] Args)
>   [0x00000] in :0  [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: WinForms_SeeInnerException --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for
>   System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Could not open display (X-Server
>   required. Check you DISPLAY environment variable) Parameter name:
>   Display   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr
>   display_handle) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in :0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Theme.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---   at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in :0
>   at MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.MainForm..ctor () [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.My.MyProject+MyForms.Create__Instance__[MainForm]
>   (MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.MainForm Instance) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.My.MyProject+MyForms.get_MainForm () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run
>   (System.String[] commandLine) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.My.MyApplication.Main (System.String[] Args)
>   [0x00000] in :0

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have an X server running. 
Without an X server there is no Display for the application to bind to.

Comment: Is there a way to start X server and run my app in the same command?

Comment: Do you have an Xserver installed? Minimal CLI installations (i,e no desktop environment) rarely come with them. Does startx produce any results?

Comment: I do now. However I still haven't figure out how to start my mono app in x-server with 1 line. I created a shell script to do it.

"
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
X -nocursor -s 0 -dpms&
mono /app/AdvancedHMI.exe&
"

Comment: startx && application

Comment: I tried that. It only starts x-server, and ignores the second part of the line.

Comment: Your script only has 1 &, you will need 2 (&&) to run both commands. Its likely X is binding to the terminal and preventing any further code being run. You may have to pipe the command into a gnome-terminal session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45984/discussion-between-thecolonel26-and-user2183032).